# Generate multi-page document in Open XML from List of data

Tags: c#, ms-word, export, openxml

For a project I am working on, I'm investigating methods that our team doesn't usually use for generating documents.  Normally, we use ActiveReports to generate a PDF that we serve up to the client, but that's not an option due to our paper size - we've been having **severe** issues getting anything that's not 8.5" x 11" to play nicely with browser-side PDF plugins, or the printers that we support.

The specific thing I'm trying to do, is to create a document with 1...n 4"x6" Index Cards.  As noted I can have a variable number of data entries that I need to generate.

The only way I've used Open XML in the past is to take a template, replace keywords with data that I wanted to inject, then serve the resulting document up to the client, as below:

**Report Class:**

```
public class ThingReport : IDisposable
{
    #region Variables / Properties

    private readonly string _templatePath = string.Empty;
    private MemoryStream _reportStream;

    #endregion Variables / Properties

    #region Constructor

    public ThingReport(string templatePath)
    {
        _templatePath = templatePath;
    }

    #endregion Constructor

    #region Methods

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _reportStream.Dispose();
    }

    public void RunReport(IList<Thing> things)
    {
        _reportStream = new MemoryStream();

        using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(_templatePath))
        {
            fs.CopyTo(_reportStream);
            _reportStream.Seek(0x00000000, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            fs.Close();
        }

        using (WordprocessingDocument pkgDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(_reportStream, true))
        {
            // Set basic properties of the document...
            pkgDoc.PackageProperties.Creator = "My App";
            pkgDoc.PackageProperties.Created = DateTime.Now;
            pkgDoc.PackageProperties.Title = "Some document";
            pkgDoc.PackageProperties.ContentType = "application/msword";

            // Read the full document text, in prep for editing...
            string docText;
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(pkgDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream()))
            {
                docText = sr.ReadToEnd();
                sr.Close();
            }

            // Replace the recipient.
            // Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb508261.aspx
            Regex recipientRegex = new Regex("«Recipient»");
            docText = recipientRegex.Replace(docText, things[0].PersonName);

            // Template has 3 fields in it; replace those fields with details of child data.
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                string presentedDate = string.Empty;
                string presentedNotes = string.Empty;
                if (i <= things.Count - 1)
                {
                    var thing = things[i];
                    presentedDate = thing.thingDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
                    presentedNotes = thing.Notes;
                }

                string dateReplaceText = string.Format("«ThingDate{0}»", i + 1);
                Regex dateRegex = new Regex(dateReplaceText);
                docText = dateRegex.Replace(docText, presentedDate);

                string noteReplaceText = string.Format("«ThingNote{0}»", i + 1);
                Regex noteRegex = new Regex(noteReplaceText);
                docText = noteRegex.Replace(docText, presentedNotes);
            }

            // Write the modified document to the stream.
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(pkgDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream(FileMode.Create)))
            {
                sw.Write(docText);
                sw.Close();
            }

            // Close the unmanaged resource!
            pkgDoc.Close();
        }
    }

    public byte[] Export()
    {
        return _reportStream.ToArray();
    }

    #endregion Methods
}
```

I've never even tried to use a Word Template across multiple data entries at once.  As this is a technology that the rest of my team has the same experience with, I can't ask them how to do this, as they know exactly as much as I do.

I did look up the [Open XML API for word documents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.packaging.wordprocessingdocument_methods(v=office.14).aspx), and some other requisite Google searches on how to get the Open XML API to do this...but I found nothing that I could make sense of.

**Question:** In what way can I take a `List<Thing>` with a variable number of members, and use Open XML to take a MS Word Template to generate a document that has a number of pages equal to the number of members, all using the exact same format?

Comment: Actually, what you should do first is familiarize yourself with how to best get your result in the Word UI. By that I mean analyse how to accomplish this using Word's built-in features - because that's what you also use in Open XML (or automation - makes no difference). For example, should this be in table format, in outline format? What should determine how a page breaks - Word has format settings you can integrate in styles to get a "smooth flow". What other formatting is required?

Comment: Once you've got a useful format, create a minimal document that contains all the elements (including styles). Save that document and open it in the Open XML SDK Productivity Tool. That will show you the underlying Word Open XML that makes up the document as well as the Open XML SDK code to generate it (if you want to use that tool). That should give you a starting point. And once you see the underlying XML that will probably tell you how to "transform" your list data...

Comment: I don't think you actually read my question.  While I did download the tool and opened my template document in it, I see a bunch of gibberish, and not any clear ways to take my single page, replicate that page as many times as I need, and replace the placeholder text on those pages with the details of my objects.  **Maybe** Open XML isn't the right technology for what I'm trying to do - I don't really know much about it - but I would like to either know that what I'm doing is either possible or impossible.

Comment: Yes, it's possible.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to create a word template with number of merge fields to map with members of your Thing/object and then perform Mail merge with List.

Using [DocIO](http://help.syncfusion.com/file-formats/docio/overview) library of Syncfusion, you can achieve it very easier. DocIO is a .NET library that reads and writes Word 2003/2007/2010/2013/2016 files. The whole suite of controls is available for free (commercial applications also) through the [community license program](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) if you qualify. The community license is the full product with no limitations or watermarks.

For example, let us create a Word document template as shown below with merge fields and consider you have a list of customer (List) details.

[image: Input Word template]

**Step 1**: Create a console application
**Step 2**: Add reference to Syncfusion.DocIO.Base, Syncfusion.Compression.Base and Syncfusion.OfficeChart.Base
        You can add these reference to your project using NuGet also.
**Step 3**: Copy & paste the following code snippet. Make sure to refer the input word template properly.

This code will produce the document as per your requirement, for each thing/customer, it will produce a separate page in the resultant Word document.

[Download Demo](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/156982/ze/DocIO-MailMerge488940256)

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Syncfusion.DocIO.DLS;
using Syncfusion.DocIO;

namespace DocIO_MailMerge
{
   class Program
   {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>();
        customers.Add(new Customer("Maria", "Anders", "maria.Anders@example.com", "USA"));
        customers.Add(new Customer("Ana", "Trujillo", "ana.trujillp@example.com", "USA"));
        customers.Add(new Customer("Antonio", "Moreno", "antonio.moreno@example.com", "UK"));
        customers.Add(new Customer("Thomas", "Hardy", "thomas.hardy@example.com", "Mexico"));

        using (WordDocument wordDocument = new WordDocument(@"Template.docx"))
        {
            wordDocument.MailMerge.Execute(customers);
            wordDocument.Save("Result.docx", FormatType.Docx);
        }

        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("Result.docx");
    }
}
class Customer
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string MailID { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public Customer(string firstName, string lastName, string emailID, string country)
    {
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
        MailID = emailID;
        Country = country;
    }
}
}
```

Note: I work for Syncfusion.